# Regarding how to store the file values into variables in Scala programming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

AM trying to read the file and store the values into variable but i am not getting correct result. Could you please help me how to do this?

1) File info :

Testval.txt :

10,10

2) Reading the file and storing the values into variable.

code :

```
val rangetab = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://clientbucket/Check/TestVal.txt")

val a = rangetab.first()

println(a)
```

Then i am getting out like (10,10). I want to store the values like 
 a = 10 and b = 10.

kindly help me how to do this?

Comment: val b=a.getAs[Int]("b")

Comment: what does println(b) print? what is the type of val a?

Answer (score 0):

Try: val res = rangetab.first()

val (a,b)=(res.get(0),res.get(1))

println(a)

println(b)